# how to create a list of records matching an ID from a JSON object?

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON object(SoftwareImageTestPlans) as input to my API,I am trying to create a record of all the SoftwareImageTestPlans matching a SoftwareImageID at line `SoftwareImageTestPlans_WithParticularSoftwareImageID = SoftwareImageTestPlans.Select(c => c.SoftwareImageID == SoftwareImageID);` which does not seem to be working as it throws an error when I try to retrieve the data later,how to fix this error?

```
SoftwareImageTestPlans :
[
  {
    "SoftwareImageTestPlanID": 0,
    "SoftwareImageID": 0,
    "SoftwareImage": "string",
    "TestPlanMasterID": 0,
    "TestPlanVersionID": 0,
    "TestPlanName": "string",
    "TCIndexList": "string",
    "TCNamesList": "string"
  },
  {
    "SoftwareImageTestPlanID": 1,
    "SoftwareImageID": 1,
    "SoftwareImage": "string",
    "TestPlanMasterID": 0,
    "TestPlanVersionID": 0,
    "TestPlanName": "string1",
    "TCIndexList": "string1",
    "TCNamesList": "string1"
  },
  {
    "SoftwareImageTestPlanID": 0,
    "SoftwareImageID": 0,
    "SoftwareImage": "string",
    "TestPlanMasterID": 0,
    "TestPlanVersionID": 0,
    "TestPlanName": "string1",
    "TCIndexList": "string1",
    "TCNamesList": "string1"
  }
]
```

API:

```
public List<SoftwareImageTestPlan> AddOrUpdate(List<SoftwareImageTestPlan> SoftwareImageTestPlans)
{
    // List<int> BuildList = new List<int>();
    IEnumerable<bool> SoftwareImageTestPlans_WithParticularSoftwareImageID = new List<bool>();

    foreach (var SoftwareImageID in SoftwareImageTestPlans.Select(sid => sid.SoftwareImageID).Distinct())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SoftwareImageID);
         SoftwareImageTestPlans_WithParticularSoftwareImageID = SoftwareImageTestPlans.Select(c => c.SoftwareImageID == SoftwareImageID);
    }

    foreach (var SoftwareImageTestPlan in SoftwareImageTestPlans_WithParticularSoftwareImageID)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SoftwareImageTestPlan.SoftwareImageID); //Throw the error mentioned below
    }
    return null;
}
```

Error:-

```
'bool' does not contain a definition for 'SoftwareImageID' and no extension method 'SoftwareImageID' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found
```

Comment: check your Json here at this link to make sure that it's valid JSON - http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: MethodMan - I already did that,perfectly valid JSON,I provided a sample aswell

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. By the time it gets to `AddOrUpdate` it's just an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies within the lines:

```
foreach (var SoftwareImageTestPlan in SoftwareImageTestPlans_WithParticularSoftwareImageID)
{
    Console.WriteLine(SoftwareImageTestPlan.SoftwareImageID); //Throw the error mentioned below
}
```

You're iterating a list of bool so in that foreach the variable SoftwareImageTestPlan is of type bool so it doesnt have a SoftwareImageID.

For that to work you could change the type of SoftwareImageTestPlans_WithParticularSoftwareImageID to a IEnumerable of SoftwareImageTestPlan

and change the line

```
SoftwareImageTestPlans_WithParticularSoftwareImageID = SoftwareImageTestPlans.Select(c => c.SoftwareImageID == SoftwareImageID);
```

to

```
SoftwareImageTestPlans_WithParticularSoftwareImageID = SoftwareImageTestPlans.Where(c => c.SoftwareImageID == SoftwareImageID);
```